# .NET Core RC2 in Service Fabric

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I want to add a new .NET Core RC2 MVC application to an existing Service Fabric cluster, but I can't figure out how I should do this.

I've looked at several RC1 examples but that hasn't gotten me any further either.
I understand you need to add an EntryPoint in your ServiceManifest.xml file.
But in the RC1 example they point to the dnx.exe, which has been removed in RC2:

```
<EntryPoint>
     <ExeHost>
        <Program>approot\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe</Program>
        <Arguments>--appbase approot\src\ChatWeb Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener</Arguments>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
        <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="5" FileMaxSizeInKb="2048" />
     </ExeHost>
  </EntryPoint>
```

What EntryPoint should I use in the RC2 version of .NET Core?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this announcement:

[Announcing ASP.NET Core RC2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/)

As you can see, your ASP.NET Core application with RC2 becomes a console application.

That said, your entry point is your EXE that comes out from compilation of your ASP.NET Core console application.

So instead on relying on DNX to pickup Main method from your Startup.cs, you setup your toolchain in Program.cs and then just build an EXE that Service Fabric will use for Entry.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

So your manifest would be something like this:

```
<EntryPoint>
     <ExeHost>
        <Program>YourApp.Exe</Program>
     </ExeHost>
 </EntryPoint>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe this is correct, but building the project doesn't provide me with a .exe file. Just an .dll. Do you know how I can set-up my project to provide me this .exe file?

Comment: @johandroid Your project must be a Console Application. Create new Service Fabric project from scratch, and select Stateless Web API. Once you create it, observe that it shows that it is C# Console Application. If you build it, you will get EXE in your bin folder. If you open PackageRoot\ServiceManifest.xml, you will notice that EXE is set as EntryPoint. Since ASP.NET Core RC2 is built with idea of OWIN and WebAPI 2, you need to setup same project structure. Keep in mind that there is no IIS in Service Fabric - Web App must be self-hosted and that is what is being setup in your Main method.

Comment: I'm at the same level, searching for an example... is there any? For now I'll follow https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2015/08/19/using-project-json-for-other-project-types/ for using the project.json etc

Comment: Did anyone try the hosting packages yet?

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned already in a comment, it does not has to be a console application. Take a look at https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting

Clone it and see that the projects of SmsService and CounterService are ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2 projects.

Comment: That is not actually right. "Sms" project in mentioned solution is actually console application - it produces an EXE in your bin/debug folder that you can run. Only addition is that within toolchain ServiceFabric hosting is added as well. If you remove lines .UseServiceFabricEndpoint("SmsTypeEndpoint") and ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("SmsType", serviceContext => new SmsService(serviceContext, communicationContext)).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); and make appSettings.json optional, you will be able to run EXE on your own PC without Service Fabric.

Comment: Well, that seems to be the default for ASP.NET Core projects, normally you would use the WebHostBuilder in Program.cs main entry point. The fact that it is a console application is hidden. With my answer I ment that you don't have to create a console application yourself, but just let it be an ASP.NET Core project. Your answer is correct as well, but I answered with a link to a sample.